# How do I parse a string into an arraylist in java?

Tags: java

I have a large string that contains fixed value fields, this group of fields can repeat from 0 to 40 times. I would like to parse this list into an arraylist but I am not sure of the best way to do this?

The string data is as follows,

```
 CountryCode = 2 character
 StateProv   = 7 characters
 PostalCode  = 10 characters
 BuildingNum = 5 characters
```

There is no delimiter the pattern just repeats

any suggestion?

Comment: You probably need a map, not a list

Comment: Is the string data exactly like you are posting/ with a new line between each value?

Comment: give example input and expected result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably just read repeated substrings:

```
private static final int PATTERN_LENGTH = 24;
....

List<Location> list = new ArrayList<Location>();

if (text.length() % PATTERN_LENGTH != 0)
{
    // throw an exception of some description; you haven't got valid data
}
for (int start = 0; start < text.length(); start += PATTERN_LENGTH)
{
    list.add(Location.parse(text.substring(start, start + PATTERN_LENGTH));
}
```

(Or perform the parsing in the boody of the loop, or whatever... the main point is you've got the substring.)

Comment: @Jon,could you provide with a example in `ideone.com` so that it could be handy for further reference.unable to understand this example here.

Comment: @Deepak, the example looks clear to me, can you expand on what is confusing?

Comment: @Deepak: Which precise part do you not understand?

Comment: why PATTERN_LENGTH is 24 and why `if (text.length() % PATTERN_LENGTH != 0)` and finally why a substring in final part.

Comment: @Deepak: PATTERN_LENGTH is 24 because that's 2+7+10+5 (i.e. the length of the whole pattern). The "if" block is to check that the text length is a multiple of the pattern length, i.e. we have a whole number of patterns. The substring is to take one instance of the pattern at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using a character array.  I am sure it can be optimized and I would like to see what changes you could apply to make it faster.  Here is my test:

```
public class Test {

public static String bigString = "USARIZONA85123-123477777USWASHING78987-458711111USCOLORAD11111-111133333";

public List<String> getValues() {
    List<String> seperatedValues = new ArrayList<String>();

    char[] bigStringArray = bigString.toCharArray();
    char[] temp = new char[24];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i=1; i < bigStringArray.length+1; i++) {
        temp[j] = bigStringArray[i-1];
        j++;
        if (i%24 == 0) {
            seperatedValues.add(String.valueOf(temp));
            temp = new char[24];
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    return seperatedValues;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    System.out.println(test.getValues());
}
```

}

Comment: Why bother copying the string to an array to start with? Just use String.substring, which won't copy the characters.